# Update a specific cell in MS Access using visual basic

Tags: ms-access, vba

good day, i would like to ask if it is possible to update a specific cell in ms access using visual basic. If it is possible, may i ask what would be the syntax to be used? Thanks!

Comment: Access doesn't have "cells". You're going to need to be much more specific with your question if you're going to get help here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

The syntax would simply be an `Update Query`.

When you say "..using visual basic". I am interpreting that as using Visual Basic for Applications. Am I correct?

You can either create the query using QBE, and pass in the parameters in the `Criteria` field within the query.

You could then run the query via code:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "YourQueryName"
```

[MS Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192746.aspx)

If that's not your preferred way, you need to look into constructing SQL strings into VBA.
Check out [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357177/access-vba-sql-query-causes-update-syntax-error). String concatenation in VBA is different than just writing SQL in Access.

Hope this helps.